# find a range of convergence (-3/2.3/2]

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Is there a series in the form of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{∞} a_n.x^n$
with a range of convergence (-3/2.3/2]? please give an example or prove it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Start with
$-\ln(1-x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n}
$
which converges for
$x \in [-1, 1)$.

Then
$-\ln(1+x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^nx^n}{n}
$
which converges for
$x \in (-1, 1]$.

Finally,
squeeze $x$ by $\dfrac23$
so it converges for
$x \in (-\dfrac32, \dfrac32]$:
$-\ln(1+\dfrac{2x}{3})
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n(2x/3)^n}{n}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n2^nx^nx}{n3^n}
$.

Comment: the last part should only be $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n2^nx^n}{n3^n}$, not $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n2^nx^nx}{n3^n}$. thank you very much for your answer